# CGColor not defined for the UIColor, need to first convert colorspace. Swift 2, Xcode 7

Tags: xcode, swift, uicolor, color-space, cgcolor

I was trying to change the color of my app´s buttons by creating the color using sliders to select the values of Red, Green, Blue and Alpha. So I created an variable which held the color created by the user.

ViewController is where the buttons are.
ChangeColors is the RGB Sliders System.

```
import UIKit

import Foundation

var buttonColor = UIColor()

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var tools: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var custom: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var support: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var donate: UIButton!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tools.backgroundColor = buttonColor
    custom.backgroundColor = buttonColor
    support.backgroundColor = buttonColor
    donate.backgroundColor = buttonColor
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

The second is the code of te RGB Slider System.

```
import Foundation

import UIKit

class ChangeColors: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var Red: UISlider!

@IBOutlet var Green: UISlider!

@IBOutlet var Blue: UISlider!

@IBOutlet var Alpha: UISlider!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func preview(sender: AnyObject) {

    let rVal = CGFloat(Red.value)
    let gVal = CGFloat(Green.value)
    let bVal = CGFloat(Blue.value)
    let aVal = CGFloat(Alpha.value)

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: rVal, green: gVal, blue: bVal, alpha: aVal)
}

@IBAction func change(sender: AnyObject) {

    let rVal = CGFloat(Red.value)
    let gVal = CGFloat(Green.value)
    let bVal = CGFloat(Blue.value)
    let aVal = CGFloat(Alpha.value)
    let color = UIColor(red: rVal, green: gVal, blue: bVal, alpha: aVal)

    buttonColor = color

}

}
```

But the app crashes as soon as it open and get the following error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -CGColor not defined for the UIColor ; need to first convert colorspace.

I really need help. Thank You.

Comment: Change the method parameter type from AnyObject to UISlider

Comment: Make sure you are passing a value ranging from 0 to 1

Comment: What type of property is buttonColor?

Comment: @user3654258 is a Global var type UIColor

Comment: try to change all UIColor's to CGColor's?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that an instance created by the `UIColor()` initialiser doesn't represent an actual color. If you look at the crash message in more detail, you'll see that it actually creates a `UIPlaceholderColor` instance – which (as the name suggests) appears to act as a 'placeholder' in the absence of any color information. Therefore you can't assign it to the `backgroundColor` of any of your views.

The fix is define a default color for your `buttonColor`. In your case I'd advise `clearColor`.

```
var buttonColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

Answer (score -1):

in my Case :
if you using colors from Assets
make sure the color name such as Class Colors